# How to capture from instensive pro in Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS using HDMI interface?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, video, c

I am trying to use PCI-X1 capture card (intensiy pro) using Ubuntu 10.04 (now) / 11.04 (failed) or Fedora (failed). None of them is yet capturing. I did my best but now i need some backup on this.

Question: Do you know what is causing my capture/input as "Frame received (#0) - No input signal detected"? Where i have another **Playstation 3** connected in the input interface.

Please find details, that i followed:

**Step 1**: Drivers      [OK]

```
$ uname -a
Linux sun-desktop 2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:13:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep magic
03:00.0 Multimedia video controller: magic Design Device a117

$ lsmod | grep magic
magic            441567  1 
$ magicFirmwareUpdater status
    magic0 [Intensity Pro]  0x1e    OK
$ ll /dev/magic/card0 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root video 10, 55 2011-09-24 10:48 /dev/magic/card0
```

**Step 2**: Output test  [OK]

[image]

**Step 3**: Input test   [FAILED]

```
A) Failed (while trying to capture)

    $ ./Capture -m2 -n 1
    Frame received (#0) - No input signal detected
    Stopping Capture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PS3 is probably putting out an [HDCP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hdcp)-protected video signal. The HDMI licensing authority requires that lossless conversion and transmission products like the BlackMagic Intensity refuse to work unless the downstream element also obeys HDCP. Since this test program doesn't have an HDCP key and your hard disk isn't offering to provide secure HDCP-protected storage, the BlackMagic card has to refuse to provide the raw frames if they want to keep their HDMI license.

The easiest way I can think of to test this is to burn a DVD of a movie you made yourself, using software that lets you turn off the copyright flag. When playing that back, the PS3 *should* send it out the HDMI port without HDCP protection. If the Blackmagic card starts letting you capture frames, you know it's an HDCP issue.

If you look around online, you may be able to find information about splitting the HDMI into separate DVI and digital audio signals, then recombining them, but I couldn't help you there. I live in the US, where it is currently illegal to even point to such information.

Comment: Honestly speaking, you are correct. Also just a comment: "In such case, its like promoting large companies to become more larger, and some creative small footprint independents trying to grow up with creative projects, should not even think of it? Its also like destroy creative mind by license policy. Thats how i see the HDCP license policy, implemented. Kind of binary dirty politics."